# Firefox integration with Sharepoint and MS Office

Tags: firefox, sharepoint, ms-word

When using SharePoint with Chrome or Edge, you can open a Word docx file, make changes, and when you save, the changes are saved in SharePoint - not on the local disk.

This does not work for us with Firefox ESR 105 and hasn't for some time.

Anyone know how we can get Firefox to integrate cleanly with SharePoint like Edge and Chrome (and even IE 11) do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Firefox disabling support for add-ons also disabled some integration with Sharepoint.

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1158193 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e250eb69-1a0a-4cee-84d8-7c376fdc80d9/office-integration-not-working-with-firefox-and-sharepoint-2016-onpremises for details.

FF disabled them for security purposes.  Not sure if this a problem for Chrome and Edge that they still allow it, or if FF should handle it.  However, for now, FF will work with Sharepoint but if you want to edit documents you then must check them out manually and check them in when done.